# apt-get error: Unable to find expected entry contrib/binary-i386/Packages in Meta-index file (malformed Release file?)

Tags: 10.10, apt, official-repositories

I am getting below error when I try to update. I had gone through the previous articles related to this question but none of them were helpless. Could you please help me to rectify this?

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/cdh/dists/lucid-cdh4/Release  Unable to find expected entry  contrib/binary-i386/Packages in Meta-index file (malformed Release file?)

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` are

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list # (deleted commented lines and deb-src)
deb in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted
deb in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates main restricted
deb in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe multiverse
deb in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates multiverse
```

Regards,
Raj

Comment: could you include your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the output of `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: cat /etc/apt/sources.list (deleted commented lines)
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe

Comment: deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse

Comment: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse)

Comment: Lot of restrictions to "Add Comment" :(

Comment: ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d
total 20
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  177 2012-12-27 18:35 cloudera-cdh4.list
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  177 2012-12-27 18:35 cloudera-cdh4.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciber ciber 255 2013-01-08 15:02 cloudera.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  162 2012-12-27 18:35 cloudera.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   62 2012-12-27 18:35 eugenesan-java-lucid.list

Comment: great, Thanks. From your comment I saw the file `cloudera-cdh4.list`. Could you insert the contents (only lines beginning with `deb`) in your question?

Comment: sure. Here is the content of cloudera-cdh4.list
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/cdh lucid-cdh4 contrib

deb-src http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/cdh lucid-cdh4 contrib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera offers a [step-by-step tutorial](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/CDH4+Installation#CDH4Installation-DebianPackage) for the installation. As far as I can tell from your comments you did everything as described there. However Cloudera only offers packages for 64Bit architecture. As your system tries to download i386 packages I assume you are running on 32Bit. In this case it is not possible to use this software.

However if you are running 64Bit you [download the deb](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/one-click-install/lucid/amd64/cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb) and then run   manually `sudo dkpg -i cdh4-repository_1.0_all.deb`. This will install the recent version on your system (but only in the 64Bit case).

Comment: You are correct. I am running on 32Bit. I will try the same on 64Bit and let you know my findings. thanks a lot! :)